# Highchart.getSVG convert to png

Tags: java, highcharts

In Highchart to I use  Highchart.getSVG() get SVG code that svg code to convert to base64 becuase that base64 value to return bean to store png image in specify path.Is this possible or any other way?

Comment: See [documentation](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/client-side-export).

Answer (score 1):

PNG is a raster format, SVG is a vector format. You'll need to perform [rasterisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rasterisation) to convert the SVG to PNG. You could use [Apache Batik](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/) to do that. Specifically, the [Transcoder API](https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/batik/using/transcoder.html) can be used to rasterize your SVG.

Comment: in javascript highchart.getSVG get time to convert PNG Base64 data URI is possible?

Comment: Not without rasterisation.